# How does Oracle 11g Interpreter a Subselect/Query generated by Hibernate and Process it?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am using **hibernate 4.2.18** and **Oracle 11g**

I have the following query, those tables have indexes, including indexes in the join columns and also, index in the index_column:

```
/*outer query generated by hibernate*/
select a as a1, 
       b as b1, 
       c as c1 
  from (
           /* inner query(the one I have mapped) */
           select a, b, c, index_column 
             from table_1
           inner join table_2 on table_1.a1 and table_2.a1
       ) this_
where this_.index_column = '123' /*parameter*/
```

The query above with the comment **inner query** is the one I have mapped in a Hibernate entity, and the outer query is the one that hibernate creates, once in runtime it tries to query the Entity with the parameter.

How does Oracle executes this final Hibernate generated query?

Being more specific - does it execute the inner query, brings the results into memory, then apply the outer filter?

```
where this_.index_column = '123' /*parameter*/
```

**Or**

Is it smart enough to understand the parameter/filter that is in the **outer query** and use execute the filter, without projecting all the results from the inner query and applying the filter, in other words as if that Hibernate Wrapping query did not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far too broad to completely answer, and really has nothing to do with hibernate, but *there is* something worth explaining:

Most (if not all) database engines use heuristics to try and complete a query as fast as possible using all the information available. This means **the entire query** is considered when the engine chooses an execution plan. Indexes are considered, past execution of identical (or very similar) queries are used to estimate complexity and so on. This is one of the key selling points for database engines - the ability to execute a query using "the best" plan...

Comment: Good point @Amit, and one more piece of information, those tables have indexes, including indexes in the join columns and also, index in the index_column